# Run sshd in Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, ssh

I found this `Dockerfile` sample [here](https://dev.to/s1ntaxe770r/how-to-setup-ssh-within-a-docker-container-i5i):

```
// version 1
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update && apt install ssh  -y
RUN service ssh start
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"]
```

When I build and run this `Dockerfile`, it runs an SSH server in the foreground, which is great.

If I use the following `Dockerfile` though:

```
// version 2
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update && apt install ssh -y
RUN service ssh start
# CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"] // without this line
```

And then run the container:

```
~$ docker run -p 2222:22 -it ssh_server
```

And try to connect to it from another terminal, it doesn't work. Seemingly this call to sshd is necessary. On the other hand, If I just install SSH in the Dockerfile:

```
// version 3
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ssh
```

And run the container like this:

```
~$ docker run -p 2222:22 -it ssh:test
~$ service ssh start
* Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd
```

Now I'm able to connect to the container. So I wonder: If the line `RUN ssh service start`
in version 1 is necessary, why isn't necessary for version 3?

To add more to the confusion, if I build and run version 4:

```
// version 4
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update && apt install ssh  -y
#RUN service ssh start // without this line
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"]
```

It also doesn't work either.

Can someone please explain those behaviours? What is the relation between `service ssh start` and `/usr/sbin/sshd`?

Comment: Why are you running sshd inside a container? It smells like an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern). I'd recommend not treating containers like VMs. If you want to break into a running container it's better to use `docker exec`.

Comment: `RUN ` are steps executed at build time only, not when you actually run the container. 
Also, when running an Ubuntu container it just starts the single CMD process in it, init/systemd will not be running.

Comment: That `RUN` command is effectively a complete no-op.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK everything is clear now:

Basically running the `/usr/sbin/sshd` is what runs the ssh server. The reason it didn't work out on it's own (version 4) is because the script that runs when you run `service ssh start` - which is the script `/etc/init.d/ssh` - creates a directory `/run/sshd` which is required for the run of sshd.

This script also calls the executable `/usr/sbin/sshd`, but since this is run as part of the build, it didn't sustain beyond the temporary container that the layer was made of. W

What did sustain is the `/run/sshd` directory! That's why when we run `/usr/sbin/sshd` as the CMD it works!

Thanks all!

Comment: Your answer is correct: /etc/init.d/ssh does stuff before calling /usr/bin/sshd, and any changes to the file system are saved to the docker image.

In addition to creating /run/sshd, the start script will also generate ssh host keys (/etc/ssh/ssh_host_*), if they do not exist.

Answer (score 3):

To build on @YoavKlein's answer, `service ssh start` can take arguments which are passed to `sshd`, so rather than

```
# Incidentally creates /run/sshd
RUN service ssh start
# Run the service in the foreground when starting the container
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

you can just do

```
# Run the service in the foreground when starting the container
CMD ["service", "ssh", "start", "-D"]
```

which will start the SSH server through `service`, but run it in the foreground, avoiding having to have a separate `RUN` to do first time setup.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the idea from @mark-raymond :)

Following docker run command with the -D flag worked for me!:

```
docker run -itd -p 2222:22 <dockerImageName:Tag> /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```